# Content slider with jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build simple content slider, when page loads I only want to show one item (image and content) and make some kind of nav that user can navigate.

This is my simple HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center ">
        <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000" data-pause="hover">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 image">
                        <img src="https://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 iot-features-content">
                        <h3> Title</h3>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary glavni">Link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item ">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 image">
                        <img src="https://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 iot-features-content">
                        <h3> Title 2</h3>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary glavni">Link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my JS code

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 4000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item:first-child').addClass('active');
});
```

Idea is to have simple nav (prev - next) and display only one item, when user clicks next displey another and so on. Also here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wvuake3j/1/

Comment: What is the issue/question? What's the jQuery for that's in the question but not in the fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to add carousel functionality to your HTML using bootstrap 4.

If you read the documentation of carousal mentioned at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/ .

According to the documentation, you don't need to add you custom javascript, try the below code.

```js
$(function(){

 $('#myCarousel').carousel({
   interval: 4000
 })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row align-carousel-items-center ">
        <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000" data-pause="hover">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 image">
                        <img src="https://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 iot-features-content">
                        <h3> Title</h3>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary glavni">Link</a>
                    </div>
     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item ">
     <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 image">
                        <img src="https://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 iot-features-content">
                        <h3> Title 2</h3>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary glavni">Link</a>
                    </div>
     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
   <!-- Navigation Control -->
   <!-- Controls -->
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
     <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help